# Java SE 6 and Jax-Ws WebServices. Whether something else is needed?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, webserver

I have implemented a product using Java SE 6 and Jax-WS 2.0 like it has been described by Sun here:
http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/07/03/jax-ws-web-services-without-ee-containers.html

The product provides SOAP-based web services. The services allow to download small FS resources and CRUD some objects persisted in DB (I am using Hibernate in order to get DB abstraction).

The new version of the product should provide a RESTFull API, so I am going to use either Restlet or Jersey.

My question is whether this solution will be stable\ scalable for 10s concurrent web clients connecting to this server?
Do I need a full J2EE package? Is a Web container only needed? Can I continue without full J2EE or container?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the stand alone version.
It will scale just fine, don't worry about scalability right now. All applications have their breaking/stress points.

So if you are doing some hands on, don't bother about the scalability.